# Why does AEM component not drag to the page?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am just getting my head around AEM version 6.2 and struggling to create a component that I can drag onto my page. I copied an existing 'working' component and changed the name in the CRXDE page. The result is the new component is visible in the left components panel but when I want to drag it nothing happens? How can I create/copy an component that is draggable?

Answer (score 0):

For a component to be droppable inside a parsys, it needs to be added using design mode...

- Go to design mode
- Configure that parsys
- Select the component which you want to drop inside parsys
- Go back to edit mode. It should now be droppable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add some text in the component jsp. Make sure cache is deleted. Also try to cq:include the component in your page component.If you are unable to do so will mean there is something wrong with the component development.